# do we have to show now that $f$ is just $1-1$ or that it is also surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given the following exercise:

Let a group $(G, \cdot)$ and $H$ a finite subgroup of $G$. For each $g \in G$,we define the sets:
$$g \cdot H= \{ g \cdot h: h \in H \}$$ 
and

$$ H \cdot g= \{ h \cdot g: h \in H\}$$

Prove that each of these sets has the same cardinality as $H$.

So,we take $f: H \to gH$ ,right?

But..do we have to show now that $f$ is just $1-1$ or that it is also surjective?

Comment: Now just define a function and show it's an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

To show that two sets have the same cardinality you must show that there exists a bijection between them. Here your map is $f:H\to gH$ defined by $f(h)=gh$. Note that $f$ is a map of *sets* and does not necessarily have any extra structure since $gH$ is not necessarily a group.

Note that $f$ is injective since $f(h)=f(h^\prime)$ implies 
$$
gh=gh^\prime\tag{1}
$$
and multiplying (1) on the left by $g^{-1}$ gives $h=h^\prime$.

To see that $f$ is surjective, let $gh\in gH$. Then $f(h)=gh$. Hence $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 2):

While Brian's approach is the most direct (and what I'd do when first taking an abstract algebra course), here's a fun modification of the problem/proof you might want to think about (depending on what you've already seen in group theory): First, for a fixed $g \in G$, construct bijections from $gH$ and $Hg^{-1}$ to the set $gHg^{-1} = \{ghg^{-1} : h \in H\}$ and then show that $gHg^{-1} \to H$ is a group isomorphism.

The result you wish to prove follows as a corollary to this, since every element $g \in G$ can be written as $g_1^{-1}$ for some $g_1 \in G$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to show that it is one to one (bijective), surjectivity only tells us that all of the element in $gH$ are mapped to, but we do not know if only one element is mapped to each element in $gH$.